Defining the clickable area around the coordinates of a node in Vis.js Network configuration
I am currently creating a hierarchical network which is supposed to represent a process chain. I am now rendering the nodes and their content as well as the shape myself, using the ctxRenderer method which is called for each node if the shape is set as “custom” within the node. This all works fine. However, the area around the coordinate of the note to select it etc. is sometimes a bit too small. Especially when I render a fontawesome icon to the text. So how can I define the clickable area of the node? A slightly too large area would not be a problem, only too small is not so good for usability.
I used google and read the documentation up and down, but found nothing suitable :-(
Vis.js Docs...
i am currently @version 9.1.9
